# Nested query - Graphql

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have a typeDefs that is not returning a nested object

I would like to query the apartment with, that has owner and document in a nested query, but it is returning null.

the file has reference to the respective data file.

```
const apartments = require('./data/apartment.json');
const person = require('./data/person.json');
const document = require('./data/document.json');
```

the apartment query is returning correctly, but the nested info (owner and respective documents) is returning null

```
query {
  apartments{
    id
    code
    owner{
      id
      name
      document{
        name
        type
      }
    }
  }


const typeDefs = gql`
type Query {
  apartments(
    id:ID
    code: String
    description: String
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String  
  ): [Apartment]
  person:[Person]
}
type Apartment {
  id: ID
  code: String
  description: String
  owner:[Person]
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
type Person {
  id: ID
  name: String
  document: [Document]
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
type Document {
  id: ID
  name: String
  type: String
  number: String
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
`
```

this is the resolver

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    apartments: () => {
      return apartments;
    },
    person: () => {
      return person;
    },
    document: () => {
      return document;
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone help to retrieve the nested data?

Comment: Your GraphQL Schema and query looks correct to me. However, I am not able to guess how your resolver works, where you need to nest the objects

Comment: server? sample apartment data? show resolvers, how related/connected?

Comment: simply not related ... no owner field resolver pointing to person data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the resolver, so I updated the field to people and updated the resolver

```
people(parent) {
      return people.filter(person => person.apartmentId === parent.apartmentId);
    }
```

This is the new schema

```
// Schema definition
const typeDefs = gql`

# A Block has a blockName and Apartments
  type Block {
    blockName: String!
    blockCode: String!
    apartments: [Apartment!]
  }

  # A Apartment has a apartmentId and people
  type Apartment {
    apartmentId: String!
    people: [Person!]
  }

  # People has a name
  type Person {
    personName: String!
  }

  # Queries can fetch a list of libraries
  type Query {
    blocks: [Block]
  }
`;
```

now the resolver map look like this:

```
// Resolver map
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    blocks() {

      // Return our hardcoded array of blocks
      return blocks;
    }
  },
  Block: {
    apartments(parent) {

      // Filter the hardcoded array of blocks to only include the respective apartment in the blockName
      return apartments.filter(apartment => apartment.blockName === parent.blockName);
    }
  },
  Apartment: {

    // filter all the people that live at the same apartment
    people(parent) {
      return people.filter(person => person.apartmentId === parent.apartmentId);
    }
  }
};
```

and the Nested query looks like this

```
query GetPeopleByBlockAndApartment {
  blocks {
    blockCode
    blockName
    apartments {
      apartmentId
      people {
        personName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for everyone that tried to help.